# What are the proposed solution for SPV scaling?

Tags: spv

Apart from Client Side filtering, are there any other solutions regarding how to scale light clients?

Maybe having centralised services hold the UTXO list, the problem would then be how to anonymise your requests to that the centralised server cannot know your IP for example.

Comment: To clarify, what do you see as the current issue for SPV scaling? Light clients seem to scale very well in practice.

Comment: @chytrik Apart from the initial sync, I think it is quite slow for the majority of the time when starting up up on the phone, my opinion may be biased as I have only used Bread Wallet's and Loaf's SPV Wallets. From my understanding, Bread only generates k child keys, so with a full HD wallet on mobile, it would be hard to scale at say 200+ addresses, no?

Comment: Electrum has the ability to [communicate entirely via Tor](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/74499/how-can-i-use-bitcoin-privately-with-the-electrum-wallet-and-tor), so the server will not know your IP address.